# Memory Retention of [submininal] information

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, cognitive-modeling, working-memory, metacognition

How effective is memory retention of [subliminal] information when specifically focusing your attention on a different focal point?

I.e... If I attempt to retain information from a lecture by playing it very low, almost subliminally, while simultaneously intentionally focusing my attention on another subject during work, will it be an effective method of memory retention for the information in the lecture while maintaining productivity in the subject I am focusing on? Or am I simply introducing another method of possible distraction that has the potential to divert the focus of my concentration away from my work, effectively decreasing my productivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very doubtful that this will really help you learn anything about the lecture. Subliminal information can prime you and influence your subsequent behaviour but I don't think you'll be able to actively recall any of that information.

There's been a recent study showing that you can become aware of subliminal information by repeating it (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-89512-w). However, this was done on sensory information and only when it was repeated within very short time frames. Not sure if this can be extrapolated to your situation.

Distractions tend to interfere with learning (https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/08/170824094045.htm) but I don't know of any study that tried it with repetition. Having said this, this would probably take many repetitions and take a very long time. Probably better to just focus on the lecture.